# Failure of interchanging differentiation and integration

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The question of interchanging differentiation and integration has been addressed on this platform ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2530213/when-can-we-interchange-integration-and-differentiation)) with sufficient references and answers.

I wanted to see with examples, the failure of this interchanging, to understand the importance of hypothesis in the theorem.

**Q.** Can one state simple examples of functions of two variables defined on a rectangle (or suitable other domain) where integration and differentiation are not interchangeable in Leibnitz rule? i.e. 
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \int_a^b f(x,t)dt \neq \int_a^b f_x(x,t)dt?
$$

Comment: $a,b$ are constants. I am considering $f(x,t)$ to be defined on some rectangle $[c,d]\times [a,b]$. However, for the purpose of examples, one may take unbounded domain if necessary, but I wanted simple examples for failure

Comment: See also [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/105769/counterexamples-to-differentiation-under-integral-sign) post.