# Stability, critical points and similar properties of solutions of nonlinear Volterra integral equations

Tags: functional-analysis, asymptotics, integral-equations, stability-theory

**I've posted also on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382398/critical-points-and-similar-properties-of-solutions-of-nonlinear-volterra-integr), but repost here once I think it's an important question and would like to get more attention. Thank you!**

I have a system of nonlinear Volterra integral equations of form

$$x(t)=x_0+\int_0^t K(t,s)F(x(s))ds$$

and I am interested on the critical points of $x(t)$, I mean maximum, minimum, increasing and decreasing intervals, nonnegativity etc.

I imagine it's impossible to get complete informations about that, but here I am asking for theorems and general results to help me to study these aspects, once is impossible know the true solution.

Thank you.

**EDIT
I am mainly interested in nonnegativity, since we need it for physically coherent solutions. $K$ is nonnegative and the signal of $F$ depends on signal of $x$. Also interested on asymptotic equilibrium when $\int_0^\infty K(t)dt=\infty$ (but $K(t)\to 0$)**.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the [hypotheses of the Leibniz integral rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2530224/123905) apply,
$$  x'(t) = K(t,t)F(x(t)) + \int_0^t \partial_1(K(t,s)) F(x(s)) \,\mathrm{d}s  \text{.}  $$
So, can you find the zeroes of $K$ and $F$?  Can you find the signs of $K$ and $F$ on various intervals?  You don't constrain $K$ or $F$ at all in your statement, so how could anyone possibly make more specific statements?

Comment: Thank you so much, and sorry for being vague. In fact, here I am asking for theorems and general results. I am sorry, please, could I find the FTC if the integrandum is dependent on $t$? I imagine that we must use Leibniz rule, but this cannot lead to a better way on my thoughts... Thank you!

Comment: @Quiet_waters : Altered to match your changed integral.

Comment: Thank you, Eric!

Comment: I am mainly interested in nonnegativity, since we need it for physically coherent solutions. $K$ is nonnegative and the signal of $F$ depends on signal of $x$. Thank you so much in advance if you could help me once again!