# Swapping Order of Differentiation & Integration - Uniqueness of Solution to $\triangle u = 0$ in $\mathbb D$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis

Following is an excerpt from Pg. $58$, Section $5.4$ *(The Poisson kernel and Dirichlet's problem in the unit disc)* in Stein and Shakarchi's *Fourier Analysis*. I do not see how the **existence of continuous derivatives** allows us to **swap the integral with the (second) derivative.** Note that the book assumes *no background in Measure Theory*, so the authors are likely *not* deducing this from results such as Lebesgue's DCT. All integrals are Riemann integrals.

---

So far, we **have proved that**: Let $f$ be an integrable function on the circle. Then, the function $u$ defined in the unit disc by the Poisson integral $u(r,\theta) = (f\ast P_r)(\theta)$ has two continuous derivatives in the unit disc, satisfies $\triangle u = 0$, and if $f$ is continuous at $\theta$, then $\lim_{r\to 1} u(r,\theta) = f(\theta)$. If $f$ is continuous everywhere, then this limit is uniform.

We **wish to show that** if $f$ is continuous, then $u(r, \theta)$ is the unique solution to the steady-state heat equation in the disc which satisfies the conditions above. This is stated as (iii) in the text. Now, please follow the argument below.

> [image]
> [image]

---

**Q1.** How does the existence of a continuous derivative ensure that we can swap the integral with the derivative?

**Q2.** Where exactly is the author swapping $\int$ with the derivative?

Note that the authors are **strictly** restricting all integrals to Riemann integrals, so this should be deducible without Lebesgue's DCT.

Thanks a lot for your insights!

---

Note:

1. $v$ satisfies the steady-state heat equation, $\triangle v = \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial v}{\partial r} + \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial\theta^2} = 0$.
2. $P_r$ is the Poisson kernel for $0 \le r < 1$.

Comment: Can you write down equation $(8)$, please? Since you are integrating with respect to $\theta$ I do not see how to interchange integration and taking the derivative (wrt $\theta$), so I'm a bit confused regarding what you are after here. Or is there any derivative wrt to $r$ involved, which you are not showing?

Comment: Check here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2530213/when-can-we-interchange-integration-and-differentiation

Comment: Thanks, @WillM. - that's helpful. However, I do not see where exactly the author is swapping the two.

Comment: Use Leibniz's rule of swapping operator with $f = \partial_\theta v$ and $\partial f  = \partial_\theta^2 v.$

Comment: @WillM. See Thomas's comment above, it does not make sense if we consider derivatives w.r.t. $\theta$ (the variable of integration). Are you suggesting derivatives w.r.t. $r$, of the equation $2\pi a_n(r) = \int_{-\pi}^\pi v(r,\theta) e^{-in\theta} d\theta$? Followed by using $\triangle v = \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial v}{\partial r} + \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial\theta^2} = 0$?

Comment: @Thomas Please see my edits and the discussion above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're swapping the derivatives with respect to $r$ with the integral. We do exactly what the text tells us: multiply $(7)$ by $e^{-in\theta}$, then integrate with respect to $\theta$, and then divide the whole thing by $2\pi$. Then, we use split up the sum into three pieces and use Leibniz's integral rule on the first two terms:
\begin{align}
0&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(\frac{\partial ^2v}{\partial r^2}+
\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial v}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2v}{\partial \theta^2}\right)e^{-in\theta}\,d\theta\\
&=\frac{d^2}{dr^2}\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}v(r,\theta)e^{-in\theta}\,d\theta\right)\\
&+ \frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}v(r,\theta)e^{-in\theta}\,d\theta\right)\\
&+ \frac{1}{r^2}\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\partial^2v}{\partial \theta^2}e^{-in\theta}\,d\theta\right)\\
&=a_n''(r)+\frac{a_n'(r)}{r}+\frac{1}{r^2}\left((-1)^2\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}v(r,\theta)\frac{d^2}{d\theta^2}(e^{-in\theta})\,d\theta\right)\\
&=a_n''(r)+\frac{a_n'(r)}{r}+\frac{1}{r^2}(-n^2a_n(r))
\end{align}
The $(-1)^2$ terms is due to integration by parts twice; also due to periodicity of $v$ with respect to $\theta$, there are no boundary terms coming from the integration by parts. The $(-n^2)$ comes from differentiating the exponential twice (we bring down the factor $(-in)^2=-n^2$). This proves that $a_n$ satisfies the ODE given by equation $(8)$.

---

As much as I would like to appeal to Lebesgue's DCT to justify the interchange of derivatives with respect to $r$ and the integral, I certainly understand you wanting a more elementary argument, though I find it surprising that this isn't justified somewhere in Stein and Shakarchi's book. Below is a simple enough statement and proof of Leibniz's integral theorem:

> **Leibniz's Differentiation Theorem:**
>
> Let $f:[a,b]\times [c,d]\to\Bbb{R}$ be a continuous function with $\partial_1f\equiv \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}:[a,b]\times [c,d]\to\Bbb{R}$ also continuous. The function $F:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ defined by
> \begin{align}
> F(x)&:=\int_c^df(x,t)\,dt
> \end{align}
> is continuously differentiable, and for each $x\in [a,b]$, we have
> \begin{align}
> F'(x)&=\int_c^d\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,t)\,dt
> \end{align}

Some remarks: this is of course far from general, but this is usually sufficient when dealing with many of the simple examples, and this only requires basic single-variable Riemann integrals, the single-variable mean-value theorem for derivatives, and the fact that continuity on a compact set ($[a,b]\times [c,d]$) implies uniform continuity. Also, one typically defines derivatives for functions defined on open sets, but here since we're dealing with partial derivatives on a closed rectangle, this is easy to define: we're just requiring that for each $t\in [c,d]$, the function $f(\cdot, t):[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$, $x\mapsto f(x,t)$ is differentiable, with appropriate one-sided derivatives interpretation at the endpoints $a$ and $b$.

Also, clearly, the more continuous partials we have, the more times we can differentiate under the integral sign (this is a simple induction), so in your case, you're assuming $v$ is $C^2$, so you can certainly apply this result twice. Now onto the proof.

> **Proof:**
>
> Fix $x_0\in [a,b]$. Let $\epsilon>0$, and choose a corresponding $\delta>0$ using uniform continuity of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ on $[a,b]$. Then, for any $h\in\Bbb{R}$ with $0<|h|<\delta$ and $x_0+h\in [a,b]$, we have
> \begin{align}
> \left|\frac{F(x_0+h)-F(x_0)}{h}-\int_c^d\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,t)\,dt\right| &\leq \int_c^d\left|\frac{f(x_0+h,t)-f(x_0,t)}{h}-
> \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,t)\right|\,dt\\
> &=\int_c^d\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(\xi_{x_0,h,t},t)-
> \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,t)\right|\,dt\\
> &\leq \int_c^d\epsilon\,dt\\
> &=\epsilon(d-c)
> \end{align}
> Note that in the middle, for each $t\in [c,d]$, we used the mean-value theorem on the function $f(\cdot,t)$ on the interval joining $x_0$ and $x_0+h$ to find some point $\xi_{x_0,h,t}$ (note that this depends on $x_0,h$ and also $t$, which is why this proof utilizes uniform continuity) in the open interval interval between $x_0+h$ and $x_0$. Now, since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, and the point $x_0\in [a,b]$ was arbitrary, this shows $F$ is a differentiable function with the derivative as stated.
> Finally, $F'$ is continuous because it is the integral of a continuous function on a compact rectangle.

For the sake of completeness, here's the theorem about continuity of integrals:

> **Continuity Theorem:**
>
> If $K$ is a compact metric space and $g:K\times [c,d]\to\Bbb{R}$ is continuous (hence uniformly continuous), then the integrated function $G:K\to\Bbb{R}$, $G(x):=\int_c^dg(x,t)\,dt$ is (uniformly) continuous on $K$.

The proof is a two-liner. Given $\epsilon>0$, choose $\delta>0$ according to uniform continuity of $g$ on the compact metric space $K\times [c,d]$. Then, for any $x,y\in K$ with distance at most $\delta$, we have
\begin{align}
|G(x)-G(y)|&\leq\int_c^d|g(x,t)-g(y,t)|\,dt\leq \epsilon(d-c),
\end{align}
so arbitrariness of $\epsilon$ shows $G$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Thanks a lot - this is an excellent answer!

Answer (score 0):

Integration by parts give
$$
\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi d\theta\ \partial^2_\theta v e^{-in\theta} = e^{-in\theta} \partial_\theta v \Bigg|_{-\pi}^\pi + n\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi d\theta\ \partial_\theta v e^{-in\theta} = -2\pi n^2 a_n(r).
$$
You also use the PDE *and* Leibniz rule to get
$$
\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi d\theta\ \partial_\theta^2 v e^{-in\theta} = -r^2 \partial_r^2 \int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi d\theta  v(r, \theta) e^{-in\theta} - r \partial_r\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi d\theta\  v(r, \theta) e^{-in\theta} = -2\pi \big(r^2 a_n''(r)+ r a_n'(r) \big).
$$

Equation (8) of the book follows.

Cheers,

Comment: I guess it is very misleading how they wrote the last sentence. I would add: "Next, use the PDE and rewrite $\partial_\theta^2 v$ in terms of $\partial_r v$ and $\partial_r^2 v.$ Finally, ..."