# Derivative of log of probability is equal to 0

Tags: probability

Assume $f_\theta$ is pdf of a continuous random variable. If we can interchange integration and derivative operation, then
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_\theta (\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log f_\theta) &=
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log f_\theta(x))\cdot f_\theta(x) dx \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} f_\theta(x) dx \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f_\theta(x) dx \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} 1 \\
&= 0
\end{align}
$$

But why can we do that? I have tried to use dominated convergence theorem, but cannot find a function to bound $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} f_\theta$.

Comment: You will need to specify $f_\theta$ if you're going to look for a bounding function.

Comment: If you see this in deriving the maximum likelihood estimates, then it is usually **assumed** that integration and differentiation for $f_\theta$ can be interchanged. This is one of the **regularity condition** for finding MLEs.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2530213/when-can-we-interchange-integration-and-differentiation)

Comment: @ムータンーオ So is this assumption true for all probability distributions? (side note: this is one statement involved in Cramer-Rao Lower bound)

Comment: This is not true. A simple example is $X \sim Unif(0, \theta)$, which you can compute the two sides to show that they are different. There are certainly more distributions of this kind, and those estimator are called **superefficient**.